# In R, compare two lists of strings, find parts of each element of the first list on the second

Tags: r, subset

**NOTE:** I have updated the question to reflect specific patterns in the data.

Say that I have two vectors.

```
   names_data <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
   levels_selected <- c('A1','A3', 'Blow', 'Bhigh', 'D(4.88e+03,9.18+e+04]', 'F')
```

I want to know how to get a vector, a data frame, a list, or whatever, that checks on the levels vector and returns which levels of which variables where selected. Something that says:

```
    A: 1, 3
    B: low, high
    D: (4.88e+03,9.18e+04]
```

Ultimately, there is a data frame `X` for which `names_data = names(data)` and `levels_selected` are some, but not all, of the levels in each of the variables. In the end what I want to do is to make a matrix (for, say for example, a random forest) using `model.matrix` where I want to include only the variables AND levels in `levels_selected`. Is there a straightforward way of doing so?

Comment: Do you control the structure of the levels_selected vector? I.e. is it always formatted as 'name+level'?

Comment: Yes. It is always formatted like that, with no spaces, hyphens or anything else in between.

Comment: The new structure is also working with my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a grouping variable after keeping the substring that contains the "names_data" in the "levels_selected" ('grp'), `split` the substring with prefix removed using the 'grp' to get a `list`.

```
grp <- sub(paste0("^(", paste(names_data, collapse="|"), ").*"), "\\1", levels_selected)
value <- gsub(paste(names_data, collapse="|"), "", 
               levels_selected)
lst <- split(value, grp)
lst
#$A
#[1] "1" "3"

#$B
#[1] "low"  "high"

#$D
#[1] "x"
```

If we meant something like

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(lst)
#  1 3 high low x
#A 1 1    0   0 0
#B 0 0    1   1 0
#D 0 0    0   0 1
```

---

Or another option is using `strsplit`

```
d1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(levels_selected,
      paste0("(?<=(", paste(names_data, collapse="|"), "))"), 
             perl=TRUE)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
aggregate(V2~V1, d1, FUN= toString)
#  V1        V2
#1  A      1, 3
#2  B low, high
#3  D         x
```

and possibly the `model.matrix` would be

```
model.matrix(~V1+V2-1, d1)
```

#### Update

By using the OP's new example

```
d1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(levels_selected,
  paste0("(?<=(", paste(names_data, collapse="|"), "))"), 
         perl=TRUE)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
split(d1$V2, d1$V1) 
#$A
#[1] "1" "3"

#$B
#[1] "low"  "high"

#$D
#[1] "(4.88e+03,9.18+e+04]"
```

It is also working with the first method.

#### Update2

If there are no characters that succeed the elements in 'names_data', we can filter them out

```
lst <- strsplit(levels_selected, paste0("(?<=(", paste(names_data, 
            collapse="|"), "))"), perl = TRUE)
d2 <-  as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lst[lengths(lst)==2]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
split(d2$V2, d2$V1)
#$A
#[1] "1" "3"

#$B
#[1] "low"  "high"

#$D
#[1] "(4.88e+03,9.18+e+04]"
```

Comment: And after that, is there a way to get a model matrix using only these levels?

Comment: @MathUser I updated with a possible outcome.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: It gives me an error, it says 'invalid split pattern'.

Comment: @MathUser I was only using your example and it didn't give any errors

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for. However, it does not work in the real dataset :/

Comment: @MathUser In the real data, the patterns could be different and regex works only based on the pattern provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111966/discussion-between-mathuser-and-akrun).

Answer (score 0):

An option that returns a list with levels as a vector stored under each corresponding name:

```
> setNames(lapply(names_data, function(x) gsub(x, "", levels_selected[grepl(x, levels_selected)])), names_data)
$A
[1] "1" "3"

$B
[1] "low"  "high"

$C
character(0)

$D
[1] "x"

$E
character(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is a handy little function I extended from the `regexpr` help example, using perl-style regex

```
parseAll <- function(data, pattern) {

  result <- gregexpr(pattern, data, perl = TRUE)
  do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(data), function(i) {
  if(any(result[[i]] == -1)) return("")
  st <- data.frame(attr(result[[i]], "capture.start"))
  le <- data.frame(attr(result[[i]], "capture.length") - 1)

  mapply(function(start,leng) substring(data[i], start, start + leng), st, le)

}))
}
```

*EDIT: It's extended because this one will find multiple matches of the patterns, allowing you to look for say, multiple patterns per line. so a pattern like: `"(?<first>[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+) (?<last>[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+)"` (from the original regexpr help) finds all instances of the pattern in each string, rather than just one.*

suppose I had data that looked like this:

```
dat <- c('A1','A2','A3','B3')
```

I could then search for this data via 
`parseAll(z,'A(?<A>.*)|B(?<B>.*)')` to get a data.frame with the levels selected:

`parseAll(dat,'A(?<A>.*)|B(?<B>.*)')`

```
     A   B  
[1,] "1"  "" 
[2,] "2"  ""
[3,] "3"  "" 
[4,] ""   "3"
```

and which selection had each level (though that may not be useful to you), I can programmatically generate these patterns as well from your vectors:

`pattern <- paste(paste0(names_data,'(?<',names_data,'>.*)'),collapse = '|')`

then your selected levels are the unique elements of each column, (it's in data.frame, so the conversion to list is easy enough)

This is my omnitool for this kinda stuff, hope it's handy

Comment: regexpr could be used to do the same, (but the function I have uses gregrexpr) he wanted the levels of the second parts, broken up by some set of patterns, in some data structure.

Comment: I think you're right that this isn't a tool for just this question, but for the class of questions "If I have data stored in a concatenated string, how do I extract that to a useful data structure in R"